# java binary to decimal

Tags: java, binary

Im having trouble converting binary to a decimal. We have to use a function for the conversion and do it by hand rather than use a predefined function. This is what I have so far, I know it is a mess but I am stuck on how to fix it. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinaryConversion {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String inString;
    int decimal;

    System.out.println("Enter a binary number: ");
    inString = input.nextLine();

    while (!"-1".equals(inString)) {
        int i;
        int binaryLength;

        binaryLength = inString.length();
public static int binaryToDecimal (String binaryString) {

    for (i = binaryLength - 1, decimal = 0; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (inString.charAt(i) == '1')
            decimal = decimal + Math.pow(2,inString.length() - 1 - i);
    }
    return (int) decimal;
}
        System.out.println(decimal);

        System.out.println("Enter a binary number: ");
        inString = input.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("All set !");
}
}
```

Comment: You appear to have one function inside another for a start. I.e. public static int binaryToDecimal can't be defined inside main

Answer (score 2):

To use a function, as your assignment requires, you have to write the function *outside* the main method, and then include a statement that *calls* the function.  So move this *above* the line that says `public static void main`:

```
public static int binaryToDecimal (String binaryString) {

    for (i = binaryLength - 1, decimal = 0; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (inString.charAt(i) == '1')
            decimal = decimal + Math.pow(2,inString.length() - 1 - i);
    }
    return (int) decimal;
}
```

Also, each function or method (including `main`) has its own variables that it uses, called *local* variables; but the local variables that each function uses are its own separate copies.  Thus, the above function won't be able to use the `binaryLength` or `decimal` variabes belonging to `main`.  You'll need to declare them inside `binaryToDecimal`:

```
public static int binaryToDecimal (String binaryString) {

    int decimal;
    int binaryLength;
    for (i = binaryLength - 1, decimal = 0; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (inString.charAt(i) == '1')
            decimal = decimal + Math.pow(2,inString.length() - 1 - i);
    }
    return (int) decimal;
}
```

Also, this function won't be able to access `main`'s `inString`, but the idea is that you've given the function the string you want to work with, which it refers to as `binaryString`.  So change `inString` to `binaryString` in the function:

```
public static int binaryToDecimal (String binaryString) {

    int decimal;
    int binaryLength;
    for (i = binaryLength - 1, decimal = 0; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (binaryString.charAt(i) == '1')
            decimal = decimal + Math.pow(2,binaryString.length() - 1 - i);
    }
    return (int) decimal;
}
```

And also note that the `binaryLength` and `decimal` variables are totally unrelated to the variables of the same name in `main`.  That means that when you assigned `binaryLength` in `main`, that has no effect on `binaryLength` in `binaryToDecimal`.  You'll need to assign it in the function.  Change `int binaryLength;` to

```
int binaryLength = binaryString.length();
```

Finally, in order to use the function, `main` will need to call it.  Put this in the `main` function:

```
decimal = binaryToDecimal(inString);
```

When `main` executes that, it will call the function and tell it to work with `inString`.  The function will call that `binaryString`, though.  The function will return a result, and then `main` will assign that result to the variable `decimal`--that means the local variable `decimal` that belongs to `main`, since the above statement is inside `main`.

I don't know if this will make your whole program work.  (It should, but I'm not sure.)  But I'm just trying to explain the details of how to use functions.

Comment: Thank you for explaining so thoroughly! I'm new to programming and it still wasn't clear to me how arrays and methods worked.

Answer (score 1):

The confusing part is with the `Math.pow`, and its complicated arguments, where off-by-one errors are easily made.

Yet, if we have a number at base 10, like

123

its value is

(((0*10)+1)*10+2)*10+3

This looks complex, but note the easy pattern: Starting out with 0, we go through the digits. As long as we have another dgit, we multiply the previous result by the base and add the digit value. That's all! No Math.pow, no complex index calculations.

Hence:

```
String s = "1010";
int value = 0;
int base = 2;
for (i=0; i < s.length(); s++) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    value = value * base;
    value = value + c - '0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I cleaned up your code, it worked just fine -

```
public static int binaryToDecimal(String binaryString) {
    int binaryLength = binaryString.length();
    int decimal = 0;
    for (int i = binaryLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (binaryString.charAt(i) == '1') {
            decimal += Math.pow(2, binaryLength - 1 - i);
        }
    }
    return decimal;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a binary number: ");
    String inString = input.nextLine();

    while (!"-1".equals(inString)) {
        System.out.println(binaryToDecimal(inString));

        System.out.println("Enter a binary number: ");
        inString = input.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("All set !");
}
```

Output

```
Enter a binary number: 
01
1
Enter a binary number: 
10
2
Enter a binary number: 
-1
All set !
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function after a little clean up.

```
        public static int binaryToDecimal (String binaryString) {
            int decimal = 0;
            int base    = 2;
            for (int i = binaryString.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (binaryString.charAt(i) == '1')
                    decimal += Math.pow(base,i);
            }
            return decimal;
        }
```